# How can we pass VarChar input to a SQL function?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2017

My table 'LoadData' is as below:

| Sequence_Code | ID | Current_Year | Record_Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17AA | 310001 | 2017 | 2017-01-01 | S |
| 18AB | 310002 | 2018 | 2018-02-22 | S |
| 19AC | 310003 | 2019 | 2019-02-10 | S |
| NULL | 310004 | 2019 | 2019-02-20 | A |

I have written a SQL function 'GetNextSequenceCode_TEST' which generates the next sequence code,
For example: if we give 'AB' as Input, the function will generate 'AC' as output.

The function is as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextSequenceCode_TEST] 

(@LastSeqAlphabet varchar(100))

  RETURNS varchar(100)

AS

BEGIN 

     DECLARE @fPart varchar(100), @lChar CHAR(1);  
              IF(@LastSeqAlphabet IS NULL OR @LastSeqAlphabet = '')   
               RETURN 'A';      

                 SELECT @fPart = LEFT(@LastSeqAlphabet, LEN(@LastSeqAlphabet) - 1);  
                 SELECT @lChar = RIGHT(@LastSeqAlphabet, 1);   
                   
              IF(@lChar = 'Z')  
              RETURN (SELECT [dbo].[GetNextSequenceCode_TEST](@fPart)) + 'A';  
               
          RETURN @fPart + CHAR(ASCII(@lChar)+1);  
   END
```

Sequence_Code is Alphanumeric,so i am supposed to consider last two Character of Sequence_Code .
Please look at the below code:

```
DECLARE @SeQCode varchar(100)   
SELECT top 1 @SeQCode = SubString(Sequence_Code,3,4)   
FROM LoadData where ID=310003

print  @SeQCode
```

Here value of the variable @SeQCode i am getting is AC.

But when i send this variable to my function, like this:

```
select GetNextSequenceCode_TEST (@SeQCode )
```

it's giving output B!, which is wrong,

I am supposed to get AD as output.

And when i pass input like

```
select GetNextSequenceCode_TEST ('AC')
```

It gives me Correct output. i.e AD

Please correct me if i am doing something Wrong. or passign input in wrong way

Comment: please show the function `GetNextSequenceCode_TEST` query

Comment: Sure,Let me add the function in the post..

Comment: @Squirrel I have just added Function code also.. please have a look..

Comment: can't see anything wrong on the function except for `SubString(Sequence_Code,3,4)` Shouldn't it be just `SubString(Sequence_Code,3,2)` ? If your `Sequence_Code` is not 4 characters, you might getting the wrong value

Comment: @Squirrel SubString(Sequence_Code,3,4) is giving me correct value as i need last 2 characters only.

Comment: if you want last two, then t should be `SubString(Sequence_Code,3,2)` OR `RIGHT(Sequence_Code, 2)`.  Also change the `print  @SeQCode` to `print  QUOTENAME(@SeQCode)`. See is there any character after `AC`. If your function is only expecting 2 character why declare as `varchar(100)` ?

Comment: check the value coming in top1

Comment: @Squirrel Your suggestion really helped me,I used  print  QUOTENAME(@SeQCode).  and i came to know that this is the issue of space..that's why it's generating next character as ! .. i just used RTRIM, and the code started working.... Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Your code appears to work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c21f034951a477a6404a7c9be56ab5e.

Comment: yes..But It was not working in my System, i am using Sql Server 2017, i have no clue why it happed.. Thanks @Gordon Linoff  for the effort you put to check my code.